# "mouseover" function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Helllo. What if I combine tips like [here](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579) with hover: 
`.on("mouseover", tip.show) .on('mouseout', tip.hide)` and `.on("mouseover", function(d){ ... }) .on('mouseout', function(d){ ... })` How can I use them at the same time?

Comment: All relevant code goes **in** the question, not just linked. Links rot, and separately, people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: What is the title supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call function inside existed callback

```
.on("mouseover", function(d){
    tip.show(d);
```